# Android menu set icon through java

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, icons

I trying to set icon on menu item through java code

```
m1.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
```

on this line my app is crashing check is error

[image]

Comment: put your activity code here

Comment: Please share more code, are you doing it inside the `onCreate` function before `setContentView` is called?

Comment: Hi, please show more code .. how does m1 come from?

Comment: It looks like `m1` is null. As others already said, please add some more code for context. Also, it is better to paste the log instead of uploading an screenshot, so visually impaired people can also understand the issue and hepefully help you

Answer (score 0):

The MenuItem is not initialized so it causes a null object reference.
you should inflate the MenuItem to be initialized in order to .setIcon(...);

Please share more code, to take a detailed solution.

Comment: Plz check my latest post I mention in detail